# I want to replace a word in a story

Tags: java, android, replace, android-studio

I want to create an app which will let me input names in text inputs and use those names in a story.

I would have three inputs named as `strGuide`, `strHost1` and `strHost2`. After filling in the names, you would a `onClick`event to go to a new page with a short story like this example:

> "Hello, I am **strGuide** and I will be accompanied today by **srtHost1** and **strHost2**. As we walk through the mansion today, feel free to ask **strHost1** or **strHost2** any questions you may have."

I want the `strGuide`, `strHost1` and `strHost2` names which can replace the same names places in the story. This is a short example. In reality, the story would be a script for the entire tour. There are also three tours, so I'd like to pick from story1, story2 or story3. I have searched for an answer, but I can't find what I am looking for.

Comment: how did you _search for an answer_ ? did you googled _"I want to replace a word in a story"_ ?

Comment: Rafa, I search for replace a word in a story in java. I am confused on the part where I am seeing I can't replace a word, it re writes the entire string. That may be a fine way to do it. I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace()` of `String`

example to demonstrate using String.replace(), and this does not cover your entire Story!

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String story = "Hello, I am strHost and I will be accompanied today by strHost1 and strHost2. As we walk through the mansion today, feel free to ask strHost1 or strHost2 any questions you may have.";
        String str = story.replaceAll("strHost1", "stringhost1");
        str = str.replaceAll("strHost2", "stringhost2");
        str = str.replaceAll("strHost", "stringhost");
        System.out.println(str);

    }
}
```

see java docs for `String`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

**Update:**
java docs:

```
replace(char oldChar, char newChar) 
          Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) 
          Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence

replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) 
          Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement
```

Another example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String story = "Hello, I am strHost and I will be accompanied today by someguy1 and anotherguy2. As we walk through the mansion today, feel free to ask someguy1 or anotherguy2 any questions you may have.";
        String str = story.replaceAll("someguy1", "someguy1peter");
        str = str.replaceAll("anotherguy2", "anotherguy2john");
        str = str.replaceAll("strHost", "stringhost");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Output:

```
Hello, I am stringhost and I will be accompanied today by someguy1peter and anotherguy2john. As we walk through the mansion today, feel free to ask someguy1peter or anotherguy2john any questions you may have.
```

Comment: prash, do I need to use replaceAll for it to work for more than one instance of the strHost1?