# Replace comma with newline in java

Tags: java

My requirement is to replace all commas in a string with newline.

Example:

```
AA,BB,CC
```

should represent as

```
AA
BB
CC
```

here's my implementation to replace commas with newline,

```
public String getFormattedEmails(String emailList) {
    List<String> emailTokens = Arrays.asList(emailList.split(","));
    String emails = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String delimiter = "";
    for(String email : emailTokens){
        stringBuilder.append(delimiter);
        stringBuilder.append(email);
        delimiter = "\n";
    }
    emails = stringBuilder.toString();
    return emails;
}
```

this method replaces all commas with a space.
can anyone point me where did I go wrong?

Comment: can you set delimiter to \r\n and see if it works

Comment: You gave us a 'should return', how about a 'this is what it does return'?

Comment: see this post in using replace() and replaceAll() methods of String http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902229/i-want-to-replace-a-word-in-a-story

Comment: `this method replaces all commas with a space` - really? I don't see any space added to the output, besides those that might be contained in the individual tokens.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked exactly as you wanted it to... Are you using an editor that does not recognize the linebreak characters? (E.g. Windows Notepad?)

Comment: Correct (though a bit circumstantial). But under windows `\r\n` is the line separatory; `\n` will not show as line break in NotePad - though in WordPad.

Comment: You should accept an answer. People want their points

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply use following code:

```
String emailList="AA,BB,CC";
emailList=emailList.replaceAll(",", "\n");
System.out.println(emailList);
```

**Output**

```
AA
BB
CC
```

Now based on above your code, your method looks like following:

```
public String getFormattedEmails(String emailList) {
String emails=emailList.replaceAll(",", "\n");
return emails;
}
```

Hope it helps:

Comment: awesome buddy!! Keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

```
String emails = emailList.replaceAll(",", "\n");
```

Comment: hehe...Maybe he loves to eloborate :)

Comment: Just a remark: I don't think correct can be "more" or "less". Either it's correct or not. Maybe some other adjective would be appropriate (like analytic, descriptive etc).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Scanner` too

```
String emails = "AA,BB,CC"
String emailsNew = replaceCommas(emails);

String replaceCommas(String a){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(a);
    scan.useDelimiter(",");
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        result.append(scan.next());
        result.append("\n");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

`System.out.println(emailsNew);` will print:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

Comment: is this method more like if there is `'comma'` then replace with `'\n'` .. if it is.. you gave me solution.. thanks